# Force first_or_initialize to assign association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Product model with a category association like this:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Then, in a method, I have:

```
c = Category.find(1) #a preloaded category.

p = Product
  .where(
    category: c,
    color: "red"
  )
  .first_or_initialize

p.category.name #triggers a query to load category
```

The category is already loaded, and it's passed into the `where()`, but when I try to access it through `p` it runs another query.

I can avoid the extra query like this, but is there a way to accomplish the same without passing `c` into `p` twice?

```
c = Category.find(1) #a preloaded category.

p = Product
  .where(
    category: c,
    color: "red"
  )
  .first_or_initialize

p.category = c #manual assignment, no query

p.category.name #now this doesn't trigger another query
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`inverse_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Setting+Inverses) option when declaring your associations

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, inverse_of: :category
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category, inverse_of: :products
end
```

Comment: This didn't resolve the issue. `p.category_id` is returning the correct result without running a query (which I believe indicates automatic inverse detection is working).  It's only when I try to load the model through `p.category` that a second query is triggered.

Comment: try loading the product through the category. `c.products.where(color: 'red').first_or_initialize`